# Creating an account on Wax test net returns wallet wallet is not unlocked

Tags: blockchain, eos

I'm trying to create an acount  following this steps on [this wax tutorial](https://developer.wax.io/dapps/deploy-your-nft-smart-contract/) () but when I run the command to create an account

```
cleos -u https://chain.wax.io/ system newaccount waxdappacct1 waxnftowner1 EOS7jEb46pDiWvA39faCoFn3jUdn6LfL51irdXbvfpuSko86iNU5x --stake-net '5.00000000 WAX' --stake-cpu '5.00000000 WAX' --buy-ram-kbytes 32
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"waxdappacct1","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

I have created all the keys as per the tutorial above, I also try an different endpoint (https://wax.greymass.com/) as the https://chain.wax.io/ is return an error even for a simple get info request.

I also try to use my wax cloud wallet created here (wallet.wax.io) with the development mode enabled, but I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone know how can I create an account to set my contract on the test net?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempting to create an account on mainnet not testnet here and your key is for a testnet account. Change your endpoint to https://testnet.waxsweden.org and it should work fine.

I actually took your class on Udemy Icaro!